# System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`17 c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

tengo el siguiente método que me permite realizar la cargar basándome en el código del presupuesto mediante una sentencia sql haciendo uso de EntityFramework.

```
 public void Obtener_Presupuesto_Version_Do(String sValue, DataGridView dataGridPre, TextBox subtotal, TextBox pordscsub, TextBox totdscsub,
         TextBox portarsub, TextBox tottarsub, TextBox total)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
                {
                    var pre = db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(a => a.PRE_COD == sValue).Select(x => new { x.PRE_COD,x.PRE_NOM_PAC,x.PRE_NOM_ODON,
x.PRE_RUT,x.PRE_DEN_PAC,
x.PRE_PIE_DEN,x.PRE_TRA_PAC,
x.PRE_VAL_PRE,x.PRE_VAL_POR,
x.PRE_VAL_DES,x.PRE_VAL_SUB,
x.PRE_VAL_POR_DSC_SUB,x.PRE_VAL_TOT_DSC_SUB,
x.PRE_VAL_TOT,x.PRE_ID,x.PRE_ELA_PRE,x.PRE_EST_REA
                    }
                    ).OrderBy(a => a.PRE_ID).ToList();
                    if(pre.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dataGridPre.DataSource = pre;
                        dataGridPre.AutoResizeColumns();
                        dataGridPre.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Posterior a esto necesito dependiendo de la necesidad del paciente hacer una inserción en el datagridview para poder añadir mas filas con informacion referente a su tratamiento a realizar, ejecuto el código y me arroja el mensaje de error descrito en la pregunta y que adjunto como imagen.

```
if (dataGridPre.Rows.Count < 32)
                {
                    valorFec = dataGridPre.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
                    //MessageBox.Show(valorFec);
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridPre.DataSource;
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["PRE_COD"] = txtCodigo.Text;
                    row["PRE_NOM_PAC"] = txtPac.Text;
                    row["PRE_NOM_ODON"] = lblOdont.Text;
                    row["PRE_RUT"] = lblCedula.Text;
                    row["PRE_DEN_PAC"] = cmbDent.Text;
                    row["PRE_PIE_DEN"] = cmbPieza.Text;
                    row["PRE_TRA_PAC"] = cmbTratamiento.Text;
                    row["PRE_VAL_PRE"] = txtValor.Text;
                    row["PRE_VAL_POR"] = txtPorDes.Text;
                    row["PRE_VAL_DES"] = txtDscto.Text;
                    row["PRE_VAL_SUB"] = txtTotal.Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
  dataGridPre.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    cmbDent.Select();
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, intentas convertir tu `DataGridView` a un `DataTable`. Dependiendo de la fuente de datos que hayas proporcionado, tendrás que optar por un método apropiado de conversión.

Es decir, si hubieses asignado un `DataTable` como fuente de datos de tu `DataGridView` entonces el casteo debería funcionar. En cambio, has asignado un `List<'a>`, o sea, una lista de tipos anónimos.

Es por ello que

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable) dataGridPre.DataSource;
```

Equivaldría a

```
List<object> source = ...
DataTable    dt     = (DataTable) source;
```

Lo que desencadena la `System.InvalidCastException` porque no puedes convertir implícitamente un tipo de lista en una tabla de datos. El compilador simplemente no sabe como hacerlo. Son tipos incompatibles entre sí de forma directa.

---

Para tu propósito, te sugiero [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44638099/9443618) propuesta por [Salah Akbari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946329/salah-akbari), que he convertido en un [método de extensión](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

```
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }
        }

        var cell = new object[dataGridView.Columns.Count];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                cell[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(cell);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Acá, la conversión de `DataGridView` a `DataTable` se aplica iterando sobre las filas y columnas del `DataGridView`, extrayendo su valor y agregándolo a un nuevo `DataTable` previamente instanciado.

Entonces, lo usarías de esta forma:

```
DataTable dt = dataGridPre.ToDataTable();
```

---

Como ves, la idea es que debes emplear un método adecuado de conversión; acá no vale aplicar casting porque tienes dos tipos incompatibles entre sí. Pero puedes leer los datos de uno y asignarlos al otro como se muestra en el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Gracias hermano, efectivamente me esta faltando un peque;o detalle que era agregar al `DataSource` del datagridview la variable dt